# Why the name Bilinear transformation.

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis we study Bilinear transformation $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d},ad-bc\neq0.$ My question is why its name is so Bilinear transformation? Is it because of $\frac{linear}{linear}?$ Please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be because :In $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d},ad-bc\neq0$,multiply$ N^r,D^r$ by $c$ and then adjust $f$ to get :$f=\frac{a}{c} + \frac{1}{\alpha(cz+d)}$,where $\alpha=\frac{c}{bc-ad}$
Clearly(In case of problem,please comment),$z$ here involves two Translations so the name  BILINEAR.

Comment: But like in Will Jaggy's post,Bilinear transformation is not universally acceptable term.Some authors name  $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d},ad-bc\neq0.$ as Bilinear Transformation but others call it Mobius Transformation or Fractional linear transformation.Interestingly,these terms are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I have found just one book that uses this name, Complex Variables: Introduction and Applications
 By Mark J. Ablowitz, A. S. Fokas

I guess there are others.

This is not standard usage. One name is Linear Fractional Transformations. [The other is Möbius transformations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)

I don't know why this usage was begun. The word bilinear is already used as something related to quadratic forms. What amounts to the same thing, in tensors.

Comment: but its not the answer..